# Pair new device over Wi-Fi not working in Android Studio Bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio, pairing

when I try to pair a device, neither QR code or Pairing code work and just get stuck searching for a device...

I have a phone with Android 11 & 12 and Wi-Fi debugging is on.

[image: Android Studio "Pair devices" dialog]

Comment: Does scanning the QR code works?

Comment: QR code code not working

Comment: No it doesn't works

Comment: What worked for me: I connected the device using cable and paired the device, after that I used the method suggested by @Mike below to connect.

Comment: wasn't working for me either, because i was using my phone's camera to scan the qr code, i added the answer where to scan it

Comment: Wireless pairing has worked for me for a year. I only have occasional issues with it, and they always seem to be IP related.

Answer (score 47):

I'm also facing the same issue. It was working fine for a couple of weeks but since then I'm no longer able to connect to my phone via QR Code or pairing code.

What's working for me is connecting via terminal.

`adb connect [phone_ip]:[port]`

The details for IP and port can be viewed at Settings > System > Developer Options > Wireless debugging (Under Debugging) > Enable it & you should be able to see "IP address & Port" here.

Comment: That worked. I also had to close the android emulator for pairing before running the connect command

Comment: I had paired my phone over wifi using the QR code and it appeared in the list of physical devices, but not in the list of available devices to run on. I did `adb connect` as suggested, and the phone then appeared twice in the list of physical devices - but did appear as an available device, which I can now deploy to. I think something is wrong in Android Studio. But `adb connect` does seem to get it working.

Answer (score 18):

Android Studio gives an option to troubleshoot device connection. I was having the same issue then I found this way.

[image]

I found in my case I need to restart the ADB, your might be different.

Comment: "restart the ADB" - worked for me.

Comment: This worked, same here

Comment: Did this, this helped somehow. But still could not connect. router provided from my isp has 2.5G as well as 5G band. for me, simply switching to 2.5G in both of my devices helped.

Comment: omg thanks it works!

Answer (score 10):

For me, my issue was that on my workstation (Windows 11), my Network profile type under `Network & internet > Wi-Fi > {Connected Wi-Fi name}` was set to **Public Network (Recommeded)**. Changing this to **Private network** allowed it to discover my Android device connected on the same network.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was my problem too.
For some reason Windows changes it back to public.

For those of you with the same problem: 
Go to Run –> secpol.msc
-> Select Network List Manager Policies
-> Double click your desired network, go to Network Location tab.
-> Change the Network location type to either Not configured, private or public.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3f4a8ef-5f3a-4fe7-b5ab-63578069d108/network-profile-is-reverting-to-public-after-restart?forum=win10itpronetworking

Comment: Worked, Thank you so much for this great observation.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer ADB wifi for wifi adb connection.
But for this you must be in same wifi network.

[image]

after install this plugin you find it on right side panel  as shown below

[image]

Now , First time you have to connect it via usb cable and after that
Click on connect
[image: Click on connect]

And That's It. You are connected wirelessly now you can remove cable.

Answer (score 4):

In my case: restarted my PC and phone together and was then able to connect via WiFi.

Sometimes the above-mentioned method doesn't work. if it doesn't work, then I restart Android Studio.

To restart Android Studio: first, click 'File' then click 'Invalidate Caches...' then click on the 'Invalidate and Restart' button.

Answer (score 3):

What helped in my case was going to Tools -> SDK Manager and on the SDK Platforms tab choosing the Androivd version of my phone. By default in only had "Android API 33" installed. Once I added "Android 11.0 (R)" and restarted the Studio I was able to connect my phone using the QR Code.

[image: SDK Platforms]

Comment: Do you need everything or just the 'Android SDK PLatform 30'?

Answer (score 2):

This is an Android Studio Bug since it does not work reliably.

Make sure you tested these steps
[Android 11 pairing over WIFI](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+)

Make sure your

> 

```
Ensure that your workstation and device are connected to the same wireless network.

Ensure that your device is running Android 11 or higher. For more informaton, see Check & update your Android version.

Ensure that you have Android Studio Bumblebee. 

On your workstation, update to the latest version of the SDK Platform-Tools.
```

For the 4th point Sdk Manager> SDK Tools > Android SDK Build Tools

You can use a plugin called ADB WI FI from the plugin marketplace in the meantime.

It does require you to plug your cable once but doesn't require it after that .
Also you can pair it with scrcpy to project your screen on your laptop

Comment: I did all these ways, but it still does not work

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the device helped me

Answer (score 2):

Turning off/on Wifi for both my laptop and phone worked for me.

Comment: I ran into the same situation today and this still worked. I don't understand the downvote

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed the issue, for this problem there are multiple solutions as different people may have a different root cause to this issue. I'll just list a checklist on the things needed to pair a device successfully.

1. Make sure your Android device is Android 11+
2. Android Studio version must be Bumblebee and above
3. Configure your Android SDK and download the required SDK tools eg.Android SDK Platform tools (You can do this through `Tools->SDK Manager`)
4. Configure your adb correctly (Turns out my adb wasn't being recognised by Android studio `Tools -> Troubleshoot Device Connection`)
5. Ensure both devices is connected to the same network. Make sure it is the same IP address and DNS on both devices.

No 4 and No 5 turns out to be the problem to me as my PC was using OpenDNS and a static IP address while my phone was using a dynamic IP address which was different from my PC's IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Mine was fixed by simply restarting Android Studio.

My speculations are sometimes using different VPNs and maybe proxies aren't predicted by Android Studio team.

Comment: The VPN was the Problem, I then had to restart both wifi, from Smartphone & Laptop. Thx a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same isuue tried every above answers then finally restarted my router and it was working

Answer (score 1):

I tried adb, but it didn't work. What works for me is:

1. Disconnect wifi on my laptop
2. On my phone, Setting -> Connections -> Mobile Hotspot and Tethering -> Turn on Mobile Hotspot as well as bluetooth tethering
3. Connect laptop to phone through mobile hotspot
4. QR code pairing.